RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn while fine tuning llama
This answer did not solve my problem.
I was trying to fine tune llama model locally using LoRA, peft. Here is my code:
import torch
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import (
    AutoModelForCausalLM,
    AutoTokenizer,
    BitsAndBytesConfig,
    TrainingArguments,
    pipeline,
    logging,
)
from peft import LoraConfig, PeftModel, get_peft_model, prepare_model_for_kbit_training
from trl import SFTTrainer

base_model_id = "/ml/models/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct"
new_model = "./models/Meta-llama3-8b-SFT2"
dataset = load_dataset('json', data_files='./datasets/done.jsonl', split='train')

def preprocess_function(examples):
    examples['text'] = [f"question: {q}, answer: {a}, url: {u}" for q, a, u in zip(examples['question'], examples['answer'], examples['url'])]
    return {'text': examples['text']}

preprocessed_dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)
preprocessed_dataset = preprocessed_dataset.remove_columns(['chunk_id', 'question', 'answer', 'url'])

bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
)

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(base_model_id, quantization_config=bnb_config, device_map="auto")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(base_model_id, add_eos_token=True, add_bos_token=True)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

peft_config = LoraConfig(task_type="CAUSAL_LM", r=2, lora_alpha=16, lora_dropout=0.01)
model = prepare_model_for_kbit_training(model)
model = get_peft_model(model, peft_config)
model.print_trainable_parameters()

training_arguments = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./results",
    num_train_epochs=1,
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=16,
    optim="paged_adamw_32bit",
    save_steps=100,
    logging_steps=5,
    learning_rate=2e-4,
    weight_decay=0.001,
    bf16=True,
    max_grad_norm=0.3,
    max_steps=500,
    warmup_ratio=0.03,
    group_by_length=True,
    gradient_checkpointing=True,
    report_to="tensorboard",
)

trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=model,
    train_dataset=preprocessed_dataset,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=training_arguments,
)

trainer.train()
trainer.model.save_pretrained(new_model)

However, this code throws an error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 68
     60 trainer = SFTTrainer(
     61     model=model,
     62     train_dataset=dataset,
     63     tokenizer=tokenizer,
     64     args=training_arguments,
     65 )
     67 # Train the model
---> 68 trainer.train()
     70 # Save the trained model
     71 trainer.model.save_pretrained(new_model)

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2164, in Trainer.train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   2162         hf_hub_utils.enable_progress_bars()
   2163 else:
-> 2164     return inner_training_loop(
   2165         args=args,
   2166         resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,
   2167         trial=trial,
   2168         ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
   2169     )

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2522, in Trainer._inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   2516 context = (
   2517     functools.partial(self.accelerator.no_sync, model=model)
   2518     if i != len(batch_samples) - 1
   2519     else contextlib.nullcontext
   2520 )
   2521 with context():
-> 2522     tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs, num_items_in_batch)
   2524 if (
   2525     args.logging_nan_inf_filter
   2526     and not is_torch_xla_available()
   2527     and (torch.isnan(tr_loss_step) or torch.isinf(tr_loss_step))
   2528 ):
   2529     # if loss is nan or inf simply add the average of previous logged losses
   2530     tr_loss = tr_loss + tr_loss / (1 + self.state.global_step - self._globalstep_last_logged)

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:3688, in Trainer.training_step(***failed resolving arguments***)
   3686         scaled_loss.backward()
   3687 else:
-> 3688     self.accelerator.backward(loss, **kwargs)
   3689     # Finally we need to normalize the loss for reporting
   3690     if num_items_in_batch is None:

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama/lib/python3.11/site-packages/accelerate/accelerator.py:2248, in Accelerator.backward(self, loss, **kwargs)
   2246     self.lomo_backward(loss, learning_rate)
   2247 else:
-> 2248     loss.backward(**kwargs)

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py:581, in Tensor.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
    571 if has_torch_function_unary(self):
    572     return handle_torch_function(
    573         Tensor.backward,
    574         (self,),
   (...)
    579         inputs=inputs,
    580     )
--> 581 torch.autograd.backward(
    582     self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs
    583 )

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py:347, in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    342     retain_graph = create_graph
    344 # The reason we repeat the same comment below is that
    345 # some Python versions print out the first line of a multi-line function
    346 # calls in the traceback and some print out the last line
--> 347 _engine_run_backward(
    348     tensors,
    349     grad_tensors_,
    350     retain_graph,
    351     create_graph,
    352     inputs,
    353     allow_unreachable=True,
    354     accumulate_grad=True,
    355 )

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/autograd/graph.py:825, in _engine_run_backward(t_outputs, *args, **kwargs)
    823     unregister_hooks = _register_logging_hooks_on_whole_graph(t_outputs)
    824 try:
--> 825     return Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
    826         t_outputs, *args, **kwargs
    827     )  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
    828 finally:
    829     if attach_logging_hooks:

RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

What should I do to resolve it?
